# Scalar and vector matrix multiplication in R

Tags: r

What is a better way to write the following code in R?

```
base_case = rep(100,10)
mid_case = rep(200,10)
high_case = rep(1000,10)

base_prob = 0.75
mid_prob = 0.2
high_prob = 0.05

ev_case = base_case * base_prob + mid_case * mid_prob + high_case * high_prob
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?  What do you mean "better"?

Comment: Do you just want to know how to matrix multiply? eg `cbind(base, mid, hi) %*% c(.75,.2,.05)`

Comment: @NealFultz , please post as an answer ...

Comment: or `cbind(base_case, mid_case, hi_case) %*% c(base_prob, mid_prob, high_prob)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to know how to matrix multiply? eg

```
cbind(base, mid, hi) %*% c(.75,.2,.05)
```